# PHP Import from CSV file

Tags: php, html

How can I import CSV file through PHP.
And the csv file having merge cell and their structure like given below. How can I do that? Please Help me ?? And thank you in advance? Can I read data from this type of csv?

[image]

Comment: by coding it. Is there anything you have tried? Where did you get stuck? Why is the CSV in that bad structure?

Comment: CSV having the right structure.But I dont know from where I have start.And How to read data from that cells.

Comment: @RossWilson Wilson this isn't useful at all. I can't understand the code.

Comment: As far as I know, CSV doesn’t even allow for that kind of structure. And your response to the first answer does not make it look like what you are reading here was actual CSV data either. Looks much more like you have some sort of “spreadsheet” data format here, ODF/Microsoft’s Office XML data format, or sth. like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a number in every cell and save as csv?
By using [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) on each line of your file, it will be clear how you can interpret the csv.

Comment: From this I can not done.Output be like given below.                          
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => PK!ȣ�4v�[Content_Types].xml ��(��T�n�0�W�?D�V��CUU]�-�L %�;��*Y'�����**krE [2] => Tn��C2�Ear�>�T�b��4�T�4DÌqDl���?

Comment: That is not saved as csv, but probably xlsx.